# Reading large file in Spark issue - python

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have spark installed in local, with python, and when running the following code:

```
data=sc.textFile('C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\train.csv')
data.first()
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-fca93c6aedeb> in <module>()
----> 1 data.first()

C:\Spark\python\pyspark\rdd.pyc in first(self)
   1313         ValueError: RDD is empty
   1314         """
-> 1315         rs = self.take(1)
   1316         if rs:
   1317             return rs[0]

C:\Spark\python\pyspark\rdd.pyc in take(self, num)
   1295 
   1296             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1297             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1298 
   1299             items += res

C:\Spark\python\pyspark\context.pyc in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
    937         # SparkContext#runJob.
    938         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
--> 939         port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
    940         return list(_load_from_socket(port, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
    941 

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.pyc in __call__(self, *args)
   1024         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1025         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1026             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1027 
   1028         for temp_arg in temp_args:

C:\Spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     43     def deco(*a, **kw):
     44         try:
---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
     46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     47             s = e.java_exception.toString()

C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.pyc in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    314                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    315                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 316                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    317             else:
    318                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1765)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:393)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:622)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:442)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1765)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:239)
```

I am sure the path is correct, as I have tried with other files in the same folder. I think the issue is with the size of the file, which is around 3.4 gigabytes.

Any help, please?

Comment: It's worth to try use scala to have a test

Comment: As @RockieYang said, you might want to launch a spark-shell and try out your code in it, to see why it is failing.

Comment: Are you sure the path is right? I have read even larger files with spark with no problem whatsoever.

Comment: @Himaprasoon am sure the folder is right, because I can read other small files from the same folder: as long as they are less than 20 MB. If I try to read larger files, I get the error.

Comment: @RockieYang I am running it in Scala (haven't used it much) and I get the following exception when I run 'new SparkContext(conf)': 

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true.

Comment: I don't feel there is a necessary to use multiple sc. Just use the sc created by spark-shell, or use sqlContext

Comment: OK, I tried it in scala, in the spark-shell, and it works well. But still doesn't work in the jupyter pyspark environment...

Comment: @RockieYang So if it works in Scala but not in python, but other files do work in python... what is the conclussion, guys? thanks

Comment: Spark is implemented in Scala. There are certainly some overhead if using other language. Which means, if it does not work in Scala, it certainly does not work in other language; if it works in other language, it certain works in Scala.

Comment: Yes, but my case is: it works in Scala, does not work in Python (Jupyter notebook)

Comment: Do you have enough memory? The default `storageLevel` is MEMORY_ONLY_SER, so you may be running out of memory in Scala, crashing the listening socket, and triggering the error. Try changing your RDD instance, e.g: `data.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)`, before calling `data.first()`.

Comment: @Escachator By looking on your whole Stacktrace, I think on Local environment you don't have enough memory in your Spark Job. I would encourage you to increase your Driver memory in Spark and try it again. The file which you're trying t reach is having a Connection Reset which is also a TimeOut, Also please handle the IOException and update the Stacktrace more.

Comment: I don't suppose it's possible that the first line of that csv file is blank.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether you are using Spark in the standalone mode or the cluster mode, the `spark.driver.memory` and `spark.executor.memory` defaults to 1GB of memory. You can add more memory to both the `driver` and `executors` by changing this configuration while starting your Jupyter notebook or in the Spark Conf file. With this you should be able to read the 3.4GB CSV file, provided you have the necessary RAM on your machine.

Comment: @KartikKannaput thank for the answer, but can you show me how to do that?

Comment: You can run `$ pyspark --executor-memory 6G --driver-memory 6G` from your shell. This would allocate `6GB` of RAM for `spark.driver.memory` & `6GB` of RAM for `spark.executor.memory`. You can allocate different values of memory depending on your system configuration and application requirements.

Answer (score 2):

As seen in the [spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) the default maximum values for the memory usage are set to 1GB.

You can see the defaults in spark configuration file, if in linux might be located in:

```
/etc/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
```

under the lines

```
spark.driver.memory
spark.executor.memory
```

But, this config must not be set through the SparkConf directly in your application, because the driver JVM has already started at that point.

When lauching spark master/slave you shoul add the memory set [arguments](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html):

```
ex: ./sbin/start-master.sh --memory 2G
```