# PySpark Standalone: java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am fairly new to using pyspark, and I have been trying to run a script that worked fine in local mode with a 1000-row subset of the data, but is now throwing errors in standalone mode with all of the data, which is 1GB. I figured this would happen as more data = more problems, but I am having trouble understanding what is causing this issue. These are the details for my standalone cluster:

- 3 executors
- 20GB of memory each
- spark.driver.maxResultSize=1GB (added this bc I thought this might be the issue, but it didn't solve the issue)

The script is throwing the error at the stage where I am converting the spark dataframe to a pandas dataframe to parallelize some operations. I am confused that this would cause issues, because the data is only about 1G, and my executors should have much more memory than that. Here's my code snippet - the error is happening at `data = data.toPandas()`:

```
def num_cruncher(data, cols=[], target='RETAINED', lvl='univariate'):
    if not cols:
            cols = data.columns
            del cols[data.columns.index(target)]
    data = data.toPandas()
    pop_mean = data.mean()[0]
    if lvl=='univariate':
        cols = sc.parallelize(cols)
        all_df = cols.map(lambda x: calculate([x], data, target)).collect()
    elif lvl=='bivariate':
        cols = sc.parallelize(cols)
        cols = cols.cartesian(cols).filter(lambda x: x[0]<x[1])
        all_df = cols.map(lambda x: calculate(list(x), data, target)).collect()
    elif lvl=='trivariate':
        cols = sc.parallelize(cols)
        cols = cols.cartesian(cols).cartesian(cols).filter(lambda x: x[0][0]<x[0][1] and x[0][0]<x[1] and x[0][1]<x[1]).map(lambda x: (x[0][0],x[0][1],x[1]))
        all_df = cols.map(lambda x: calculate(list(x), data, target)).collect()
    all_df = pd.concat(all_df)
    return all_df, pop_mean
```

And here's the error log:

```
    16/07/11 09:49:54 ERROR TransportRequestHandler: Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectInputStream.java:2424)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1383)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:258)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anonfun$deserialize$1.apply(NettyRpcEnv.scala:257)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.deserialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.internalReceive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:588)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:577)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:170)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:104)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:104)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So my questions are:

1. Why is giving the workers 20GB of memory not enough for this 1GB dataset?
2. In general, is it a good idea to load the data into memory like I am doing here or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Although your cluster has 20GB of memory have you set `spark.driver.memory` & `spark.executor.memory` to more than 1GB, explicitly? Their default values are 1GB, you can try setting a larger value.

Comment: Seems like that is allowing for it to work - thanks!

Comment: Glad that worked. I have answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106820/reading-large-file-in-spark-issue-python/38260668), a little more in detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For whoever might find this post useful - it seems that the issue wasn't to give more memory to the worker/slaves, but to give more memory to the driver, as mentioned in the comments by @KartikKannapur. So in order to fix this I set:

```
spark.driver.maxResultSize 3g
spark.driver.memory 8g
spark.executor.memory 4g
```

Probably overkill, but it does the job now.

Comment: The way I do it is by passing these as arguments to the pyspark command: pyspark --driver-memory 5G --executor-memory 10G